# How can I direct a domain to a locally-hosted webserver?

Tags: nginx

I have a domain name hosted with Hostinger, and a local webserver running nginx, but I'm new to this and have no idea how to link the two. I've set A (host) on my domain to route to my public ip address, but this doesn't work, and just times me out. Pinging my domain name results in packets being sent, but none being received. 
port 80 is portforwarded, and port checkers say the port is open. my firewall is off for the time being.

I don't know if I have to do anything with nginx besides setting server_name in my site .conf file to my domain name (server_name mysite.xyz;)
Thanks for the help guys, I'm new to webservers but have hosted many gameservers in the past)

Comment: Can you access your web-site via IP?
Can you access your site from local network?
How did you get your IP? Did you use dynamic DNS?

Comment: Yes, I can access via IP, both local and public. IP gathered from srcds (source gameserver, it shows public ip on startup) and I don't know what a dynamic DNS is, so..

Comment: First, add and an entry to your hosts file and test it like that. If you still can't access your site via domain name, it means that the problem is in the server config

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but I don't wanna mess this up
i would add
`127.0.0.1 mydomain.xyz`
right?

Comment: First try it like this. As you posted. And second with the public IP

Comment: okay, so it's not going to conflict with localhost, right? i mean i guess i'll find out XD

Comment: Your nginx is listening on localhost

Comment: Okay, after doing both `127.0.0.1 invalidmusic.xyz` and `<public ip> invalidmusic.xyz` and rebooting after both it still times out with no response

I just double checked and the domain is set to `@ routes to <public ip>`

Comment: Then your server is not setup to listen on that domain name. Post you nginx and site confs here

Comment: nginx confs should be default? uhh i can't remember if i changed them or not, but chances are they're unchanged
and as for pterodactyl.conf in sites-available and sites-enabled they're both set to `listen 80; server_name invalidmusic.xyz;`

Comment: Follow some tutorial for installation for your operating system to know how they should be. There might be something overwriting your configs

Comment: The only things I've done to this server is install xrdp and followed the docs on the pterodactyl panel site, and let me see if they edit any default nginx settings

Comment: Nope, no default settings are touched. Let me watch a tutorial real quick and I'll get back to you. Thanks for your time, it means a lot to me :)

Comment: Alright, after a complete wipe of nginx and setting everything up again (making extra sure that the info is correct) it still can't connect (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)
I think I'm going to need to show you my dns settings for my domain and see if they're correct or not, but I'd rather not do that on the open internet, so do you have some means of contact like discord? if so, my current id is tempname#2098, add me on there if possible, if not then that's fine.

Comment: After some more research, (and a nice typo) when I type `nginx` it outputs `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)` and I'm assuming it's referring to the port and not the `0.0.0.0` part, after some more testing I've found it says that no matter what port I put `listen` to in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/pterodactyl.conf`. It says this even after killing anything on port 80 with `sudo fuser -k 80/tcp` and restarting nginx. Whether this is useful or not I don't know, but I thought I might share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

**Turns out I'm an idiot.**
I already knew this, but it turns out somewhere along the way I've fixed the problem, but I don't know where. I'm an idiot because I had a brainfart and kept trying to connect to the domain (which routes to a local server) and wondering why it wasn't working. Turns out the site works fine and I just need to re-evaluate my life choices.